# What was the motive for kidnapping Eri in the 1st episode of Railgun season 2?

Tags: a-certain-scientific-railgun

In the first episode of Railgun season 2, Erii Haruue gets kidnapped.

[image]

But why? What did they want with Erii?

Does it have something do to with the level 6 experiment from the first season?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They just needed to keep Anti-Skill at bay until they could make their escape. The two thugs original intended purpose was to break the pyrokinetic esper out of custody as he was about to be transfered to an Anti-Skill hospital.

[image: Don't come any closer!]

They clearly didn't need her as they tossed her from the helicopter in order to lose Mikoto who was using her powers to pin the helicopter to the ground.